# Managing history records with JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I need to implement Historization in the sense that we must have a new record for any updated record. Besides, I **dont want  to store data in a separate history** table. Also, **i dont need new columns to be added** ( like start_date & end_date ).

Im working with JPA and my model is as below ( just for example )  :

```
@Entity
public class Game implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idGame;
    private double gameValue;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="config")
    private GameConfiguration gameConfiguration;

    // Getters and setters ..
}

@Entity
public class GameConfiguration implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long confId;
    // and so on ..
    }
```

And what i want is : when i update a record, let's say 'gameValue', a new row appear with the new value of 'gameValue' and different 'gameConfiguration'.

Example :

IdGame      ||      GameValue      ||       config

---

1           ||         150         ||             10

And after updating :

IdGame      ||      GameValue      ||       config

---

1           ||         150         ||             10,

2           ||         240         ||              11

Comment: if you dont want a new table nor additional columns this is pretty much impossible with any technology in existence. You could add UPDATE listeners of sorts - which manipulate incoming statements and effectively break program logic but that wont actually work reliably without refreshing your entire JPA cache after each and every statement. Your requirements are impossible. You **need** audit tables or columns ... tables are the preferred way to go since it enables you to keep history once the current data-set is being deleted.

Comment: Can you explain how  2 || 240 || 11 related to 1 || 150 || 10?